# Python shell says no module named usb but linux shell doesn't

Tags: pyusb, python

I was looking for some documetation on pyusb . Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178445/how-can-the-pyusb-be-understood/5179057#5179057) and tried to use Lennart Renegro's answer.

`import usb` in python shell on IDLE gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import usb
ImportError: No module named 'usb'
```

However, I ran this program using `python first.py` on bash:

```
import usb

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor = 0xfffe, idProduct = 0x0001)

if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')

dev.set_configuration()

cfg = dev.get_active_configuration()

interface_number = cfg[(0,0)].bInterfaceNumber
alternate_setting = usb.control.get_interface(interface_number)
intf = usb.util.find_descriptor(cfg, bInterfaceNumber = interface_number, bAlternateSetting = alternate_setting)

ep = usb.util.find.descriptor(intf, custom_match = lambda e: usb.util.endpoint_direction(e.bEndpointAddress) == usb.util.ENDPOINT_OUT)
assert ep is not None

ep.write('test')
```

and bash return the following error(which I was expecting because I hadn't connected any usb devices atm):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "first.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
ValueError: Device not found
```

What is happening here? And how do I read those docs?

Comment: Are you sure the python version of IDLE and your bash shell are the same?

Comment: @Chiel92 I'm not sure. The first line of python shell says Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux. I don't know the version of my bash shell and don't know how to check it either. Is there a command I can run to see that?

Comment: In your shell run: `>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.version)`

Comment: Probably you meant to run the script on IDLE. Afterall we know the version of the Python used in the Linux shell already, and we just need to compare it to the version in IDLE.

Comment: Oh ok. python shell- 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09) 
[GCC 4.8.1]

Comment: No I can already see it printed as an auto generated text. I was inquiring about bash but according to @justhalf that is already known

Comment: I'm confused. Can you run the `import sys; print sys.version` on IDLE and post the result? The one you posted already is for the Python in Linux shell, right? The one that you get after running `python` in bash, right? I assume "Python shell" refers to the one in bash. Is it not the case?

Comment: @justhalf No that one is for the python in IDLE. Sorry for creating the confusion. I thought python shell referred to IDLE.

Comment: So then run `python` on your Linux shell, it will show you the Python version.

Comment: @justhalf Linux shell - Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2

Comment: So they are different, as @Chiel92 has suspected. You may want to change the version in your IDLE to match the one in Linux shell.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776359/python-idle-change-python-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion above, apparently the python versions of IDLE and the default python shell are different. You installed `pyusb` for python 2.7.5, while you want to use it on IDLE which runs python 3.3.2.

To fix this problem, either

- install `pyusb` for python 3.3.2
- make sure to use python 2.7.5 with IDLE. For the latter you can have a look at the question @justhalf pointed to: [Python IDLE: Change Python Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776359/python-idle-change-python-version)

Comment: On the official page it says pyusb runs on any python version >= 2.4

Comment: That is correct, but installing some package for python 2.7.5 doesn't make it available for python 3.3.2 automatically. You have to install the *same package* for 3.3.2 separately.